# Using ArcPy to ungroup group layer in MXD?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arcpy, group-layer

I am looking for a way to ungroup a group layer using arcpy... (instead of having to open the mxd and right-click on the layer to choose "Ungroup"...)

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(pathToMyMxd)
df = mxd.activeDataFrame

newLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(pathToMyLayerFile)
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, newLayer, "BOTTOM")

mxd.save()

layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(df)
for layer in layers:
    if layer.isGroupLayer:
        # layer.ungroup()???
```

Answer (score 3):

If the layer is a group layer then it *should* support [ListLayers](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/ListLayers/00s30000002n000000/), from this then you can iteratively [move layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/MoveLayer/00s300000029000000/) and then finally, after all layers are moved out then [remove the layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/RemoveLayer/00s300000039000000/).

The reference layer for *move layer* should be the group layer, then the moved layers will (by default) go before the group layer.

I know it's not a one-liner but is effectively what you want.